# Is there a force applied to fixed pivot in a 90° linkage in the direction of applied force of one end in linkage (with two applied forces on linkage)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

With a 90degree linkage with a fixed pivot and two moving pivots such as shown in the picture, on both ends there is a force applied, but each with a different force. Is there eventually a force applied to the fixed pivot in the direction of the smaller force applied in the linkage?[image: 90degree linkage with a fixed pivot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the pin must react the applied forces to achieve balance.

[image: fig]

Now if the center of mass is moving, and it undergoes any acceleration, then the forces to do so come from the applied forces *and* the pivot forces. So the pivot reaction forces are going to be slightly different from the static case.

---

So like any other problem in dynamics, you have to start with the kinematics, and describe what are all the allowed motions of the center of mass

[image: fig2]

The acceleration of the center of mass from the diagram above is

$$ \overline{\mathrm{acc}} = \pmatrix{-c_x \omega^2 + c_y \dot{\omega} \\ c_y \omega^2 + c_x \dot{\omega} } $$

so the net forces acting on the part are found by Newton's second law

$$ \pmatrix{F_x \\ F_y} + \pmatrix{ 100 \\ -50} = m \,\,\overline{\mathrm{acc}} $$

But this depends on the rotational acceleration $\dot{\omega}$. To find it you need the torque balance at the center of mass. Assume $R$ is the radius at which the external forces are applied.

$$ (R-c_y) 100 - (R-c_x) 50 - c_y F_x - c_x F_y = I_{\rm CM} \dot{\alpha} $$

So the rotational balance depends on the forces. You see there is a coupled system here and to solve it, use the forces in to the expression above to come up with

$$ \dot{\omega} = \frac{ R (100-50) }{I_{\rm CM} + m (c_x^2+c_y^2)} $$

which then can be used to back solve the forces

$$  \begin{aligned}
  F_x & = -100 - c_x m \omega^2 + \frac{ 50 R m c_y}{I_{\rm CM}+m (c_x^2+c_y^2)} \\
  F_y & = +50 + c_y m \omega^2 + \frac{ 50 R m c_x}{I_{\rm CM} + m (c_x^2+c_y^2)} 
\end{aligned} $$

Each force has 3 parts. First part is the static balance (as mentioned initially in this answer), the second part is the centrifugal forces due to speed, and the last part are the Eulerian forces due to rotational acceleration.

Note that for a fairly uniform pie segment the following approximation is reasonable for the MMOI about the pivot $I_{\rm CM} + m ( c_x^2 + c_y^2 ) \approx \frac{m}{2} R^2$. Also reasonable is $c_x = c_y \approx \frac{4 R}{3 \pi}$

The brings the Eulerian forces equal to $$ \frac{50 R m \tfrac{4 R}{3 \pi} } { \tfrac{m}{2} R^2} = \frac{400}{3 \pi} = 42.44$$ That is quite a significant portion of the external load imbalance that goes into accelerating the pivot.

Comment: In case the object can move freely around the fixed pivot with minimum friction, there would be an acceleration of the object given that the two applied forces on the linkage are different i guess. But what would be the forces on the fixed pivot in that case, and in which direction? I thought that since the object will move opposite of the smaller applied force, that the smaller applied force won't impact the fixed pivot, because it is cancelled out by the larger applied force. Is this way of thinking wrong?

Comment: The acceleration of the CM occurs in two directions. The radial inwards direction towards the pivot due to rotation speed of $r \omega^2$ and the tangential acceleration $r \dot{\omega}$ due to the change in speed. The net forces must equal to mass times these accelerations.

Comment: @EdwinFransen - see update in the answer with a much more detailed analysis and description of what contributes to the forces.

Comment: Eventually it won't result in an applied force on the fixed pivot in the direction of the smaller initial applied force of 50N(cy)?

Comment: @EdwinFransen - I don't understand the question! This analysis involves one instant in time, so there is no eventually unless you explain how conditions change over time. Also the static portion is always going to be presented even if the part isn't moving.

Comment: I understand my comment was confusing. I meant to ask if in this instance there is no applied force on the fixed pivot in the direction of the smaller initial applied force of 50N(cy)?

Comment: @EdwinFransen - then the static portion of $F_y$ would be zero, but the Eulerian part would be double, since the torque imbalance goes from $50R$ to $100R$.